# Default download folder for pictures in Private Firefox

Tags: firefox

During a private window session in Firefox, pictures I want to `"Right Click > Save Image as"` seem to default into a different folder.

Normal browsing and other downloads not using the above method are set to the default `"Home/<user>/Downloads"` folder, so I'm fine with these. But because I switch often between private and normal browsing, it can get annoying having to dig for a separate folder for all my downloads.

How did this happen and How do I change it back to using the default download folder?

If ever, can I set separate default download folders for these methods?

Answer (score 0):

Accidental fix. Long story short:

1. Go to the url: [about:config](http://about:config). It will warn you that it's dangerous. Continue
2. Look for `browser.download.lastDir`. There's a search bar at the top.
3. Double-click the `browser.download.lastDir` row. A prompt will appear.
4. Edit as needed. Click `Okay`. Close your browser to refresh.

---

Following [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1012963) link in Mozilla's FAQ, I saw how to alter its variables. Unfortunately, the steps after that didn't correct it, so I searched for other variables.

`browser.download.lastDir` contained the folder Firefox defaulted to, so I tried changing it. It worked.

My other questions haven't been answered yet so I'm open to other, more detailed answers.